# Return matching rows from Google Sheets matrix

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, lookup

Given a worksheet with rows and columns, and boolean values in the body, I want to return a list of rows where the values are true for a specific column.

e.g.

| Vehicle/Colour | Green | Blue | Red |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sport | True | False | True |
| SUV | True | True | False |
| Sedan | False | False | True |

I want to return a list of all vehicles that come in Red.

I've created the sheets and started to try some operations using lookup() and vlookup() but got stuck when it became obvious what I was trying wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A2:A,filter(B2:D,B1:D1="Red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!

This worked great, once I turned on iterative calculation. But what if I wanted to turn it around? - i.e. List all colours that SUVs come in?

Comment: 1, the formula does not need iterative calculation enabled at all. 2, try: `=filter(B1:D1,filter(B:D,A:A="SUV"))`

Comment: Yeah, turned the setting off and it continued to work. Thank you for your help; both equations work perfectly.